# Como puedo ordenar el print de un método de webservice (soap) con estructura de datos?

Tags: python, webservice

estoy empezando en python y me gustaría saber como puedo usar print con esta estructura de datos pero implementar un orden de lista circular enlazada o lista doblemente enlazada? y entonces al momento de hacer print los datos saldrán ordenados de otra manera?

```
from suds.client import Client

url ='https://www.banguat.gob.gt/variables/ws/TipoCambio.asmx?WSDL'

cliente = Client(url)

resultados = cliente.service.TipoCambioRango("23/02/2021", "23/02/2022" )


print(resultados)
```

Comment: A cuál estructura de datos te refieres? A la salida de consumir esa operación en el webservice? Son unos Vars, cada uno con cuatro atributos...

Comment: @Alfabravo si, a la salida de esa operación, entiendo que son 4 atributos, podrías ayudarme en como puedo ordenar esos atributos para que me los muestre como una lista enlazada? necesito hacer un método antes para llamarlo y luego implementarlo ? Muchas gracias

Comment: Bueno, tienes que implementar la lógica para armar nodos, cada uno con apuntador a otro nodo (o a otros si es doblemente enlazada). Busca eso, impleméntalo y ya después es sólo instanciar Nodos, asignarles los valores de tus resultados y usar lo que hiciste para enlazar los nodos y recorrer la lista

Comment: Alguien ya le aclaro, como formular el tema y lo ayudo